# GTK - which lib-files to be included in a c-app

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have installed gtk3 for my c-app development and the problem is that I do not know WHICH lib-files that should be included? Could somone give a tip or link how to select the lib-files needed?

I installed a plugin-program for PKG-config into Eclipse but the only thing that it does is to show all the libfiles and I can check wich of these I want to include in the project. But how could I poosibly know WHICH of these to select?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

pkg-config has dependency tracking so you should only need to select gtk+-2.0 and that will pull in everything you need.

Comment: `gtk+-3.0`, as question is tagged `gtk3`

Comment: Yes if it is actually gtk3, the screenshot only shows gtk2 is installed.